# Exposing port 80 and 443 on Google kubernetes loadbalancer service

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I followed  [the guestbook tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/guestbook) from Google and created my own configuration files from it. So farm everything is working fine.
Now, I would like to expose the port 80 and 443 from my webserver pods. I know how to do it in the controller configuration file (see below), but not in the service configuration file.
Any clue how to do it please?

This is my controller configuration file:

```
{
  "id": "webservers-controller",
  "kind": "ReplicationController",
  "apiVersion": "v1beta1",
  "desiredState": {
    "replicas": 3,
    "replicaSelector": {"name": "webservers"},
    "podTemplate": {
      "desiredState": {
        "manifest": {
          "version": "v1beta1",
          "id": "webservers-controller",
          "containers": [{
            "name": "webservers",
            "image":"gcr.io/myapp/webservers:latest",
            "ports": [
              {"name": "http-server", "containerPort": 80},
              {"name": "https-server", "containerPort": 443}
            ]
          }]
        }
      },
      "labels": { "name": "webservers" }
    }
  },
  "labels": {"name": "webservers"}
}
```

This is my service configuration file:

```
{
  "id": "webservers",
  "kind": "Service",
  "apiVersion": "v1beta1",
  "port": 80,
  "containerPort": "http-server",
  "selector": { "name": "webservers" },
  "labels": { "name": "webservers" },
  "createExternalLoadBalancer": true
}
```

This is the commands that I do to setup my load balancer:

## create cluster

```
gcloud alpha container clusters create webservers --machine-type n1-standard-2
```

## create controller

```
gcloud alpha container kubectl create -f webservers-controller.json
```

## create service (load balancer)

```
gcloud alpha container kubectl create -f webservers-service.json
```

## open port 80

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create webservers-node-80 --allow=tcp:80 --target-tags k8s-webservers-node
```

## open port 443

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create webservers-node-443 --allow=tcp:443 --target-tags k8s-webservers-node
```

## show lb IP

```
gcloud compute forwarding-rules list
```

## create health checks

```
gcloud compute http-health-checks create webservers-80
gcloud compute target-pools add-health-checks k8s-webservers-default-webservers --http-health-check webservers-80 --region europe-west1
```

Do you have any clue how to expose the 443 port on the load balancer?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in v1beta1. To expose multiple ports you have to use v1beta3:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/api/v1beta3/types.go#L879

AFAIU it will be released in v0.15

PR: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/pull/6182

Comment: Ok, that's a pretty bad news... Do you have any idea when v0.15 will be released?

Comment: v0.15 should be released this week. Thanks for bearing with us as we improve things!